# robot framework: open keyword from report

Tags: robotframework

`robot framework` report open automatically keywords that failed:

[image]

So I wonder if there is a way to automatically open `teardown` keyword although it pass.

Answer (score 2):

There is cli command to do this. You can find the more information about it in [Robot framework user guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatically-expanding-keywords)

The syntax of commands is like -

```
robot --expandkeywords name:SeleniumLibrary.CapturePageScreenshot tests.robot
rebot --expandkeywords tag:example --expandkeywords tag:another output.xml
```

The discussion related to this functionality can be found on this [github thread](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2698)